# How is the UserAttributeSimilarityValidator supposed to be used in Django REST Auth?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-auth

I am testing a REST API I wrote in Django, but this validator does not work as intended. I read [the docs on this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#included-validators), but I need more than a description; I need a working example.

I have it defined in *settings.py* as is the default.

```py
# my_app/settings.py

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME':
        'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    ...
]
```

However, when I run the test, I get an unexpected and undesired success.

```py
# api/authentication/tests.py

body = {
    'username': 'frank',
    'email': 'frank@example.com',
    'password1': 'frank@example.com',
    'password2': 'frank@example.com',
}

response = self.client.post(url, body, format='json'))
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
> ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_register (api.authentication.tests.AuthTests)
Ensure we can register a user and test for validation errors.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/matt/Repositories/my_app/back-end/api/authentication/tests.py", line 108, in case_password_has_email
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
AssertionError: 201 != 400

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.275s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Am I missing the point of this validator? Am I just using it wrong? My intended behavior is for a 400 response to be sent with an error message, like the other validators allow for. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Exactly how does your register view looks like?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I import from `django-rest-auth` as such: `re_path(r'^register/', include('rest_auth.registration.urls')),`. The source is here: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/blob/master/rest_auth/registration/views.py

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit 1

The repo I referenced is no longer maintained, as the project has moved here: https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth. Documentation is here: https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth. Basically, just use pip package `dj-rest-auth` instead of `django-rest-auth`.

#### Edit 2

Looks like the PR in the old repo hasn't been added to the new one, so that'll have to change.

#### Original Answer

There's a PR open for this bug here: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth/pull/482

Install with pip:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/dgilge/django-rest-auth@patch-2
```